# Let A be a non-empty set and $f:\emptyset \rightarrow A$, why f must be 1-1?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let A be a non-empty set and $f:\emptyset \rightarrow A$, why f must be 1-1 ?

This is a part of my Sets Numbers and Functions' mid-term test, I'm still confusing about it...

Comment: Well, let's start with: what does it mean for a function to be 1-1?

Comment: @NoahSchweber $\forall x,y\in S,f\left( x\right) =f\left( y\right) \Rightarrow x=y$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a function is not injective, this means there exists $x,y$ in the domain of the function such that $x\neq y$ and $f(x)=f(y)$.

But the domain of $f$ is $\varnothing$...

Answer (score 2):

If $f:B\to A$ is *not* $1$-$1$, there must be $b_1,b_2\in B$ such that $b_1\ne b_2$ and $f(b_1)=f(b_2)$. In your problem $B=\varnothing$; there aren’t even $b_1,b_2\in\varnothing$ such that $b_1\ne b_2$, never mind whether $f$ takes them to the same thing in $A$ or not.

Comment: Eight seconds. Which one of us is getting slow? :-)

Comment: @Asaf: Hey, I’m getting old! :-)

Comment: Well, I'm not getting any younger either! :-P

Comment: @Asaf: Nyaa, nyaa, can’t catch me!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I'm confusing that who is quicker? my client shows Asaf is a little bit quicker, is it right?

Comment: @Andi: Yes, he was teasing me because he was eight seconds faster. By all means go ahead and accept his answer.